# A name for this kind of directed tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let's define a directed graph as a 4-tuple $E = (E^0, E^1, r, s)$ where $E^0$ is the set of vertices, $E^1$ is the set of edges, $r: E^1 \to E^0$ is a map assigning a range to every edge, and $s: E^1 \to E^0$ is a map assigning a source to every edge. A **sink** is a vertex $v$ for which $s^{-1}(v) = \varnothing$.

I'm looking for a standard name for this kind of directed tree graph:

- $E^0$ is finite
- $E$ has exactly one sink $v_0 \in E^0$.
- $E$ is connected (this means the corresponding undirected graph is connected).
- $E$ is acyclic (this means there are no directed cycles).
- $|s^{-1}(v)| = 1$ for every $v \in E^0 \smallsetminus \{v_0\}$.
- $|r^{-1}(v_0)| \ge 1$.

For example

$$\begin{align} \bullet \longrightarrow \bullet \longrightarrow &\bullet \longrightarrow \bullet^{v_0} \\& \underset{\bullet}\uparrow \end{align}$$.

I think it is possible to omit the connectedness condition (it is implied by its being acyclic and having only one sink). Are there any other conditions which may safely be omitted and deduced from the others?

Comment: It appears that those are precisely the digraphs that you get by starting with a rooted tree and orienting each edge towards the root. That is, if $u$ and $v$ are adjacent vertices in the tree, either the unique path from $u$ to the root contains $v$, in which case orient the vertex from $u$ to $v$, or it does not, in which case the unique path from $v$ to the root contains $u$, and we orient the edge from $v$ to $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that if you reverse all of your edges, you have an [*arborescence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)), which according to the article is also called a *directed rooted tree*, an *out-arborescence*, and an *out-tree*. The article notes that what you have has been called an *in-tree* and an *anti-arborescence*, among other things.